# Operator theory of the Hessian

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, differential-operators, unbounded-operators

How can I learn more about the operator theory of the Hessian? The Hessian of a function $u : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb R$ over a domain $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ is the matrix of second derivatives $D^2 u$.

The Hessian can be seen as an unbounded linear operator $D^2 : X \subseteq L^2(\Omega,\mathbb R) \rightarrow L^2(\Omega, \mathbb R^{n \times n})$,
where $X$ denotes the domain of the unbounded operator.

The natural question is then which choices of the domain yield a densely-defined closed Hessian. Note that the maximal choice of domain is the Sobolev space $H^2$, and I am particularly interested about "reasonable" boundary conditions.

Comment: The Hessian is at least defined for all $C^2$ functions. Since $C^\infty$-functions are dense in $L^2$ we can set $X=L^2$.

Comment: This cannot be a closed operator. What is the Hessian in $L^2$ of, say, a non-continuous function?

Comment: Seems like a natural choice would be $X=H^2_0(\Omega)$, the Sobolev space of order 2 with Dirichlet boundary conditions.  Other choices of boundary conditions are also possible depending on your domain.

Answer (score 1):

If  you have a closed, densely defined  operator $A: D(A)\subset H_0\to H_1$, $H_0, H_1$, Hilbert spaces,  then you can define on $D(A)$ the graph norm

$$\Vert u\Vert_A:=\Vert u\Vert_{H_0} +\Vert Au\Vert_{H_1}. $$

The space $D(A)$ with the above norm is a Banach space.

If $X\subset D(A)$, then the restriction of $A$ to $X$ is closed  iff  $X$ is closed in $D(A)$ with respect to the norm $\Vert-\Vert_A$.

In the case at hand we take $\newcommand{\bR}{\mathbb{R}}$

$$H_0= L^2(\Omega,\bR),\;\; H_1:= L^2(\Omega,\bR^{n\times n}), $$

$$D(A)= H^2(\Omega),\;\; Au=D^2 u. $$

In this case the norm $\Vert-\Vert_A$ is equivalent to the norm  $\Vert-\Vert_{H^2(\Omega)}$ (think interpolation inequalities.)

Finding "boundary conditions"   so that the corresponding operator is closed and densely defined is equivalent to finding  closed subspaces of $H^2(\Omega)$ that are dense in $L^2(\Omega)$.  Observe that any closed subspace of $H^2(\Omega)$  can be described asa the kernel of a bounded operator $B: H^2(\Omega)\to H$, where  $H$ is some Hilbert space. (The operator $B$ gives the "boundary" condition $Bu=0$. )